# How to get the specific time from any Timezone in Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have managed to get a specific timezone using the TimeZone utility, for now I am using the .getDefault as an example. However I cannot get the exact time in the country with just this, so I was wondering how would I implement it? And would I have to use the calendar? Below is my code.

```
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
String TimeZoneName = tz.getDisplayName();
int TimeZoneOffset = tz.getRawOffset()/(60 * 60 * 1000);

t.setText("default time zone:" + 
        TimeZoneName + " : " +String.valueOf(TimeZoneOffset) + tz.getID() );
```

this comes with default timezone: Greenwich Meantime, gmt:0, Europe/Dublin, and I would like it to display the exact time on the end. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @gravinSweeney is my answer resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Joda Time has a complete list of`Canonical ID` from where you can get TimeZone depending on the `Canonical ID`.

So, if you want to get the local time in New York at this very moment, you would do the following

```
// get current moment in default time zone
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    // translate to New York local time
    DateTime dtNewYork = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
```